# Rundeck login failed on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, rundeck

I'm running rundeck community version on AWS ECS configured with terrform. While it takes me to the login page, it doesn't take me to dashboard upon entering `admin` `admin` for username and password as mentioned [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/#login).

My ECS task logs show the login was successful, below is a log message:

```
INFO audit.AuditLoggerPlugin - Audit Event: AuditEvent {Timestamp=Fri Jun 23 16:23:46 GMT 2023, ActionType='login_success', UserInfo={username='admin', userRoles=[admin, user]}, RequestInfo={serverHostname='ip-x-x-x-x.ec2.internal', serverUUID='some-random-uuid-value-here', sessionID='node01xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', userAgent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}, ResourceInfo={resourceType='user', resourceName='admin'}}
```

But my browser window keeps spinning forever and timesout at some point. Do I need to set up any persistence with ECS for my container? If so how do I do that?

Alternatively, I tried running it locally with a measly `docker-compose.yml` and it logs me in successfully.

```
version: "3"

services:
  rundeck:
    image: rundeck/rundeck:4.13.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - 4440:4440
    volumes:
    - data:/home/rundeck/server/data
    environment:
    - RUNDECK_SECURITY_HTTPHEADERS_ENABLED=false
volumes:
  data:
```

Comment: Make sure to define the external address to access the rundeck instance, use the `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL: http://external_ip_or_dns`, take a look at this cloud example: https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/blob/master/cloud/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Thanks @MegaDrive68k, I just gave it a try in the ECS env variables, and it didn't work again :(

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved the issue by setting the below env vars

```
RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL: https://my_url
RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED: 'true'
```

Thanks @MegaDrive68k for pointing me here.
https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/blob/master/cloud/docker-compose.yml